# Can I install Internet Explorer 8 in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer, downgrade

I'm on windows 8 and I need to attend web counselling to get me a seat in college. In windows 8, I have got IE 10 by default but the site says ***"USE ONLY IE 6.0 TO 8.0"***

So can I downgrade the version of IE?

Comment: Did you try using e.g. Firefox or Chrome with User Agent Switcher? Some web pages whine about needing old IE, but actually work if you pretend to be using IE by changing your user agent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably need to use vmware, by the way, did you try to open it with chrome, firefox or something else ?

Comment: @SriHarshaChilakapati VM is easier than running it in compatibility mode?

Comment: @Griffin, he probably have a VM already in hand.

Comment: @Griffin I can't take any risk with compatibility mode. It is this counselling that decides my life.

Comment: @SriHarshaChilakapati ..... VMs are a risk too I would assume.

Comment: @SriHarshaChilakapati good luck for your college, you need some fortune ...

Comment: @AntonyLee Thanks. Counselling is starting tomorrow. And results will be on 17th.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use internet explorer nearly enough to know this off the top of my head (I use it to install other browsers and when I accidentally click it) however my extensive googleing has told me that there should be a internet explorer compatibility mode. It's not a full blown downgrade but it may work. [Here is a link](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/use-compatibility-view#ie=ie-10) to the Windows site that describes a lot of this.

After this might wanna ask them to include this on their site (assuming it works).